# Apache Beam Golang Dataflow run keep on hold

Tags: go, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using the Apache Beam Go SDK, and runner as dataflow. However, still stuck on

```
failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"sdk\" with CrashLoopBackOff:
```

I try to rebuild the container by following the Apache Beam [suggestion]: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/CONTAINERS.md

I push the new build container to Google Container registry.

However, this problem still remains.

Could someone provide information relative to this?

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow doesn't officially support the Apache Beam Go SDK. Some users have had been able to use it though. I suspect that this release may have had issues. You may be able to try a different version.

You may be able to discuss with other users on the [Beam mailing list](https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/) about which versions have worked for them (though, unsupported).